# Calculating Weekly Returns from Daily Time Series of Prices

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, finance

I want to calculate weekly returns of a mutual fund from a time series of daily prices. My data looks like this:

```
A        B      C        D        E
DATE     WEEK   W.DAY    MF.PRICE WEEKLY RETURN
02/01/12    1    1       2,7587
03/01/12    1    2       2,7667
04/01/12    1    3       2,7892
05/01/12    1    4       2,7666
06/01/12    1    5       2,7391    -0,007
09/01/12    2    1       2,7288
10/01/12    2    2       2,6707
11/01/12    2    3       2,7044
12/01/12    2    4       2,7183
13/01/12    2    5       2,7619    0,012
16/01/12    3    1       2,7470
17/01/12    3    2       2,7878
18/01/12    3    3       2,8156
19/01/12    3    4       2,8310
20/01/12    3    5       2,8760    0,047
```

The date is (dd/mm/yy) format and "," is decimal separator. This would be done by using this formula: (Price for last weekday - Price for first weekday)/(Price for first weekday). For example the return for the first week is (2,7391 - 2,7587)/2,7587 = -0,007 and for the second is (2,7619 - 2,7288)/2,7288 = 0,012.

The problem is that the list goes on for a year, and some weeks have less than five working days due to holidays or other reasons. So I can't simply copy and paste the formula above. I added the extra two columns for week number and week day using WEEKNUM and WEEKDAY functions, thought it might help. I want to automate this with a formula or using VBA and hoping to get a table like this:

```
WEEK    RETURN
 1     -0,007
 2      0,012
 3      0,047
.       
.       
.
```

As I said some weeks have less than five weekdays, some start with weekday 2 or end with weekday 3 etc. due to holidays or other reasons. So I'm thinking of a way to tell excel to "find the prices that correspond to the max and min weekday of each week and apply the formula (Price for last weekday - Price for first weekday)/(Price for first weekday)".

Sorry for the long post, I tried to be be as clear as possible, I would appreciate any help! (I have 5 separate worksheets for consecutive years, each with daily prices of 20 mutual funds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it in one formula:

```
=(INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($D$2:$D$16)/(($C$2:$C$16=AGGREGATE(14,6,$C$2:$C$16/($B$2:$B$16=G2),1))*($B$2:$B$16=G2)),1))-INDEX(D:D,MATCH(G2,B:B,0)))/INDEX(D:D,MATCH(G2,B:B,0))
```

You may need to change all the `,` to `;` per your local settings.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Scott Craner, you saved me lots of time. I would appreciate if you could check the edit I made to my question.

Comment: Do not change the question after getting an answer.  Create a new question.  It opens up the current answers for down votes. @orkanoid

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't know that. Should I delete the edit and create a new question now or is it too late?

Comment: no rollback the edit and ask a new question. @orkanoid

Answer (score 1):

I would solve it using some lookup formulas to get the values for each week and then do a simple calculation for each week.

Resulting table:

```
H   I           J           K           L           M     
    first       last        first val   last val    return
1   02.01.2012  06.01.2012  2,7587      2,7391      -0,007
2   09.01.2012  13.01.2012  2,7288      2,7619      0,012
3   16.01.2012  20.01.2012  2,747       2,876       0,047
```

Formula in column I:

```
=MINIFS($A:$A;$B:$B;$H2)
```

Fomula in column J:

```
=MAXIFS($A:$A;$B:$B;$H2)
```

Formula in column K:

```
=VLOOKUP($I2;$A:$D;4;FALSE)
```

Formula in column L:

```
=VLOOKUP($J2;$A:$D;4;FALSE)
```

Formula in column M:

```
=(L2-K2)/K2
```

Comment: FWIW: MINIFS and MAXIFS are only available on Office 365 Excel.  If not you will need to use AGGREGATE or an ARRAY MAX(IF()).  Also since none of those are array formulas you can use full column references.  One last note.  Replace the `WRONG` in the forth criterion of the VLOOKUP with `FALSE`.

Comment: @ScottCraner thx for the clarification. Sorry for the `WRONG`, it slipped into while translating into English.

Comment: I guess I can't use the MINIFS function. Keeps giving me a #NAME? error. How should I use the AGGREGATE and ARRAY MAX(IF()) functions @ScottCraner?