# Calculating Weekly Returns from Daily Time Series of Prices v2

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, finance

This is a slightly adjusted version of the question here: [Calculating Weekly Returns from Daily Time Series of Prices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115152/calculating-weekly-returns-from-daily-time-series-of-prices) which was answered by @Scott Craner:

I want to calculate weekly returns of a mutual fund from a time series of daily prices. My data looks like this:

```
A        B      C        D        E
DATE     WEEK   W.DAY    MF.PRICE WEEKLY RETURN
02/01/12    1    1       2,7587   -0,0108
03/01/12    1    2       2,7667
04/01/12    1    3       2,7892
05/01/12    1    4       2,7666
06/01/12    1    5       2,7391    
09/01/12    2    1       2,7288    0,0067
10/01/12    2    2       2,6707
11/01/12    2    3       2,7044
12/01/12    2    4       2,7183
13/01/12    2    5       2,7619    
16/01/12    3    1       2,7470    0,0511
17/01/12    3    2       2,7878
18/01/12    3    3       2,8156
19/01/12    3    4       2,8310
20/01/12    3    5       2,8760 
23/01/12    4    1       2,8875
```

The date is (dd/mm/yy) format and "," is decimal separator. This would be done by using this formula: (Price for first weekday of next week - Price for first weekday of current week)/(Price for first weekday of current week). For example the return for the first week is (2,7288 - 2,7587)/2,7587 = -0,0108 and for the second is (2,7470 - 2,7288)/2,7288 = 0,0067.

The problem is that the list goes on for a year, and some weeks have less than five working days due to holidays or other reasons. Some weeks start with weekday 2, some end with weekday 3. So I can't simply copy and paste the formula above. I added the extra two columns for week number and week day using WEEKNUM and WEEKDAY functions, thought it might help. I want to automate this with a formula and hope to get a table like this:

```
WEEK    RETURN
 1      -0,0108
 2       0,0067
 3       0,0511
.       
.       
.
```

I'm looking for a way to tell excel to "find the prices that correspond to the min weekdays of two consecutive weeks and apply the formula "(Price for first weekday of next week - Price for first weekday of current week)/(Price for first weekday of current week)".

I would appreciate any help! (I have 5 separate worksheets for consecutive years, each with daily prices of 20 mutual funds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you can generate your column `E` with this formula in `E2` :

```
=IF(B2=B1, "", (VLOOKUP(1+B2, B3:D9, 3, FALSE) - D2)/D2)
```

It's a VLookup limited on the next 7 rows from each row that declares a new week.

Copying into all cells will give the result indicated in your first tableau. To transform this result into to the list `(Week, Return)` is a matter of a filter that hides blanks from `E`.

Notice that a problem could occur if the `WeekNum` restarts from one when a new year is reached, but since you say that each of your sheets is for one (calendar) year, it shouldn't happen.

Comment: Thank you @A.S.H, replacing the comas with semicolons the formula worked perfectly. I manually checked for weeks that have less than five weekdays, i.e. weeks that start-end with weekdays other than 1-5. No problems. It will study the IF and VLOOKUP functions to figure out what this formula actually does, thanks again!

Comment: @orkanoid Glad to know it helped :). Basically the `IF` is used to display only at rows that have a new week number. The core is the `VLookup`, and we relied on the fact that it is guaranteed to return the first matched row.